# Backbone отправка файла изображения на сервер

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Недавно начал изучать фреймвок *backbone* не могу понять как отправить изображения на сервер, заголовок запроса такой `application/json`. Как поменять или изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузку файла на сервер я делаю напрямую, не из модели. Вот пример кода.

```js
var classView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  ...
  
  // Bind event click to button
  events: {
    'click .button-upload': 'onUpload'
  },
  
  // Handler button click
  onUpload: function(e) {
    var options = {};
  
    e.preventDefault();
  
    // Get file with Input File
    var file = this.$('input[type="file"]').get(0).files[0];
  
    // Create FormData
    var formData = new FormData();

    // Append file to FormData object
    formData.append('file', file);

    // Call trigger before upload
    this.trigger('upload:before', options);
  
    // Send file to server
    Bacbone
      .ajax(_.extend({
        url: '/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
      }, options))
      .then(_.bind(function(response) {
        // success
        this.trigger('upload:success', response);
      }, function(responce) {
        // error
        this.trigger('upload:error', response);
      });
  }

  ...

});

new view = new classView();
  
// your other code
```

PS код написал по памяти, но в целом идея должна быть понятна.

PSS Так же можно этот код переделать и для модели. Если надо будет, отпиши, помогу.